# Identify tree with gray ridged bark and large cordate leaves

Tags: identification, trees

The leaves are big and the stem is thin

[image]

Comment: Tropical? Where is this tree?

Answer (score 1):

This is Elephant Ear Fig; Ficus auriculata.  Nice figs!

[Ficus auriculata](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71WWinUDF0L._SL1000_.jpg)

[Ficus auriculata](https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8329/8117727939_7abcfdc858_b.jpg)

[bark, Ficus auriculata](https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6024/5926920698_1a8d10166d_b.jpg)

[leaf, ficus auriculata](https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6158/6162146329_3c203e03f0_b.jpg)

[bark of ficus auriculata](https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7194/13305256804_24ec59a6ce_b.jpg)

I've seen some of these images labeled Ficus auriculata with serrated margins.  Primarily new leaves.  This must be in India?

[bark, Ficus auriculata still more mature not showing leaf scars](https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1818/29149204817_4abeb0f466_b.jpg)

[bark, leaves Ficus auriculata](https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2805/10428850764_717cfccf4b_b.jpg)

Comment: Hi Stormy, we are looking for answers with more detail.  How did you identify it?

Comment: I've been having problems with my 'puter...I'll keep trying.

Comment: @Stormy - I'm not seeing the ridges on the trees in the photos you've linked to. Perhaps it's a related species?

Comment: Jurp, there are pictures of younger trees showing what I think are leaf scars, petiole leaf scars.  I haven't been able to up load...you could be right that this is a related species or a variety of the same but...the leaves are fairly definitive for the species; Elephant ear?  I was worried more about the leaf margins.  Some of the images under this species show serrated margins...mostly the younger growth?  The pictures that showed serrated margins I dismissed as mistakenly IDd.  Where is Bamboo!?

Comment: Ugh, I just tried to upload a younger tree's bark.  Did it work?

Comment: https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7194/13305256804_24ec59a6ce_b.jpg

Comment: How does this look for leaf scars and similarities of the bark?

Comment: Upper center of the photo looks better, but I still don't think it's quite right. Also - and it's difficult to be certain - the leaf venation on the fig seems much more pronounced than in the OP's photo. Could be due to leaf age... It would definitely help if we had a photo of the base of the trunk - that would be definitive, I think.

Comment: Jurp, trying to ID via pictures alone is sorta kinda irresponsible.  That is what they continue to pound into Master Gardeners.  Goes against the grain for sure.  Without being able to touch, turn, dig in the soil, smell...we are lucky to make IDs POSITIVELY for certain!  Bamboo did an incredible job!  I like to start a 'conversation' of yes or no or maybe until we get more information that the OP is unlikely to know to give us.  I don't care about being wrong.  Bothers me that just because everyone agrees via a photograph then that is what the ID must be!

Comment: Let's keep working on this question until we all agree?  Be nice to get more information, such as zone, country, micro climate.  Figs are tropical and subtropical but I've known them from nurseries in zone 4 and 5!  This is what they looked like because it is hard to get them to maturity with winters. Long skinny trunks with a few leaves at the ends.  What are you looking for at the base of the trunk, Jurp?  Maybe a few old figs?  Or at least fruits, buds?  Or a flare?